# Component illogically doesn't re-render on props change

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a weird problem with React-Redux app. One of my components doesn't re-render on props change which is updated by action 'SET_WINNING_LETTERS'. github repo: https://github.com/samandera/hanged-man

setWord.js

```
const initialWordState = {
  word: []
};

const setWinningLetters = (wordProps) => {
  let {word, pressedKey} = wordProps;
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(pressedKey) && word[i].letter.toUpperCase() == pressedKey) {
      word[i].visible = true;
    }
  }
  return {word};
}

const setWord = (state = initialWordState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_WORD': return Object.assign({}, state, getWord(action.word));
    case 'SET_WINNING_LETTERS': return Object.assign({}, state, 
 updateWord(action.wordProps));
  }
  return state;
}

export default setWord;
```

In Index.js in this function the actions are triggered

```
handleKeyPress(pressedKey) {
    store.dispatch({
      lettersProps: {
        word:this.props.word,
        pressedKey,
        missedLetters: this.props.missedLetters
      },
      type: 'SET_MISSED_LETTERS'
    });
    store.dispatch ({
      wordProps: {
        word:this.props.word,
        pressedKey
      },
      type: 'SET_WINNING_LETTERS'
    });
    this.showEndGame(this.props.word,this.props.missedLetters);
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    fetchWord(this.statics.maxWordLength);
    window.onkeydown = () => 
    {this.handleKeyPress(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))};
  }
```

And in PrimaryContent.js Winning and Missing Characetrs are rendered

```
  import React from 'react';
  import {connect} from 'react-redux';
  import store from '../reducers/store';
  import Hangedman from './Hangedman';
  import AspectRatio from './AspectRatio';
  import Puzzle from './Puzzle';
  import MissedCharacters from './MissedCharacters';

  const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
    return {
      word: store.wordState.word,
      missedLetters: store.missedLettersState.missedLetters
    }
  }

  class PrimaryContent extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();
}


renderDisabledPuzzles(amount){
  return Array.from({length: amount}, (value, key) => <AspectRatio parentClass="disabled" />)
}

renderLetters(word) {
  return word.map(function(letterObj, index) {
    let space = (letterObj.letter==' ' ? "disabled": '')
    return(
      <AspectRatio parentClass={space} key={"letter" + index}>
        <div id={"letter" + index}>{letterObj.visible ? letterObj.letter : ''}</div>
      </AspectRatio>
    )
  }) ;
}

render() {
  let disabledCount = this.props.puzzles - this.props.word.length;
  let disabledPuzzles = this.renderDisabledPuzzles(disabledCount);
  let WinningLetters = this.renderLetters(this.props.word);

  return (
    <div className="ratio-content primary-content">
      <Hangedman/>
      <MissedCharacters missedLetters={this.props.missedLetters}/>
      <Puzzle>
        {disabledPuzzles}
        {WinningLetters}
      </Puzzle>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrimaryContent);
```

MissedCharacters works well while {WinningLetters} doesn't. 
The action 'SET_MISSED_LETTERS' works perfect, while 'SET_WINNING_LETTERS' works only when 'SET_MISSED_LETTERS' gets updated. It means when I press one or more letter that wins they won't display until I press the letter that is missing. When I press the missing letter the component that is parent for both missing and winning letters re-renders. I was trying to pass props to  PrimaryContent from it's parent but I get the same. I tried to separate {WinningLetters} in it's own component wit access to redux store but it works even worse and stops updating even when MissedCharacters updates. Can you detect where I've made a mistake?

Comment: Please provide an example using https://codesandbox.io, I can't help you without looking through your current code base (for example you didn't provide code of your reducers).